# unmarshal errors: cannot unmarshal !!seq into config.ScrapeConfig

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to set up my Prometheus YAML file to include the proxy option. As shown in the configuration documentation, it should be:

```
[ proxy_url: <string> ]
```

I've tried to add this in various ways to my very basic YAML file but promtool check config `prometheus.yml` gives me either:

```
 FAILED: parsing YAML file prometheus.yml: job_name is empty
```

or:

```
 FAILED: parsing YAML file prometheus.yml: yaml: unmarshal errors:
 line 13: cannot unmarshal !!seq into config.ScrapeConfig
```

as error messages.
My `.yml` file currently looks like this and produces the second error message:

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

rule_files:
  # - "first.rules"
  # - "second.rules"
 
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
     - targets: ['localhost:8000']
  - [ proxy_url: http://placeholderForProxy ]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
     - targets: ['localhost:8000']
    proxy_url: http://placeholderForProxy
```